# Simplifying after using product rule

Tags: calculus

Question: differentiate $y=\cos2x\cos4x$

So far I've used the product rule and gotten

$-2\sin2x \cdot \cos4x + \cos2x \cdot (-4\sin4x)$

And from there have gotten to

$-2 \sin2x(2\cos^2x - 1 + 2\cos^2x - 1 \cdot 6\sin2x \cos2x)$

But now I don't know how to get to (the expected answer of) $-2\sin2x(6\cos^2 2x - 1)$

Comment: I have fixed your $\LaTeX$. Please check to verify that the accuracy of your post has not been tampered with.

Comment: @ahaanRungta thanks, I'm not quite used to the syntax yet, the information in the post is still correct

Comment: It's alright; thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \begin {align*} -2 \sin 2x \cdot \cos 4x - 4 \sin 4x \cos 2x &= - 2 \sin 2x \cos 4x - 8 \sin 2x \cos^2 2x \\&= -2 \sin 2x \cdot \left( \cos 4x + 4 \cos^2 2x \right) \end {align*}$$Now, use the fact that $ \cos^4 x = 2 \cos^2 x - 1 $ and see if you can finish.

---

To finish things off: $$ \begin {align*} -2 \sin 2x \cdot \left( \cos 4x + 4 \cos^2 2x \right) &= -2 \sin 2x \cdot \left( 2\cos^2 2x - 1 + 4 \cos^2 2x \right) \\&= - 2 \sin 2x \cdot \left( 6 \cos^2 2x - 1 \right). \end {align*} $$

Comment: I can't quite work out how you got to that last line, when I did it I got $-2 sin2x (cos4x +4cos^2 2x) $

Comment: @Paul Sorry, I typoed! Thanks for pointing it out. Fixed.

Comment: it happens to the best of us. I'm not sure but I thought $cos^4 x = 2cos^2 2x -1$ ?

Comment: @Paul No, the double-angle cosine identity states that $ \cos 2\theta = 2\cos^2 \theta - 1 $. Hence, $ \cos 4x = 2 \cos^2 2x - 1 $.

Comment: So how can you add $2cos^2 x$ and $4cos^2 2x$ ?

Comment: @Paul Not sure what you mean. I just edited the last step into my answer $-$ hope it makes sense now.

Comment: Is that last part meant to be $ 6cos^2 2x $ ?

Comment: @Paul As you can see, today is my day to typo. Fixed again. Does it make sense now?

Comment: it happens, and yes now I understand it. Thank you for being patient with me

Comment: @Paul Thank you very much for the upvote/accept! And you're welcome. You are a patient student yourself. :)

Answer (score 0):

As the answer involves $2x$ only as angle,

$$y=\cos2x\cos4x=\cos2x(2\cos^22x-1)$$

Now apply product rule

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-2\sin2x(2\cos^22x-1)+\cos2x[2\cdot2\cos2x(-2\sin2x)]$$

Now take out $-2\sin2x$ as common factor.

Point to be noted, we don't need to match with  the answer supplied as long as the approach is right..

Also product rule can be avoided unless mandatory using [Werner formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html)

Comment: Almost as St Paul said, "In mathematics house are many mansions"

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, Do you find any mistake or possible improvement ?

Comment: I was just supporting your nice sentence "we don't need to match with the answer supplied as long as the approach is right.."

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, As different views, so different paths to realization:) Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

$$-2\sin2x \cdot \cos4x + \cos2x \cdot (-4\sin4x)= \\ =-2\sin 2x \cdot (\cos^2 2x - \sin^2 2x) + 4\cos 2x \cdot 2 \sin 2x \cos 2x=\\=2\sin 2x (\sin^2 2x-\cos^2 2x -4\cos^2 2x)=\\=2\sin 2x(1-\cos^2 2x-\cos^2 2x-4 \cos^2 2x)=2\sin 2x(1-6\cos^2 2x)=\\=-\sin 2x(6\cos^2 2x-1)$$

First you use formulas $\cos 2\alpha=\cos^2 \alpha-\sin^2 \alpha$ and $\sin2\alpha=2\sin \alpha \cos \alpha$, next $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$.